# Mysql can't join two tables columns into one show

Tags: mysql

I want to show two columns summarize data.

- `table1` - count all fields that the id same as the id on the `show_users` table.
- `table2` - sum all values that the id same as the id on the `show_users` table.

This is my query:

```
SELECT show_users.id, COUNT(`table1`.id) as sum_fields , SUM(`table2`.count) as count_all
FROM `show_users` 
LEFT JOIN `table1` ON `show_users`.id = `table1`.id
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `show_users`.id = `table2`.id
GROUP by show_users.id 
ORDER BY sum_fields DESC
```

The `table2` results are fine, but the `table1` count isn't correct values...
Why is that?

Comment: because in join like this count is for the joined table not for the isolated one.

Comment: i mean count value for table1 is not exect because it is for joined table

Comment: OK, but when I remove the left join for table2 syntax from the query its working and does count correctly.

Comment: I found solution I put DISTINCT like this COUNT(DISTINCT `table1`.id)

Comment: oh then its gud you got what you want.

Comment: Are you sure the results of ``SUM(`table2`.count)`` are correct? Did you try your query without the join to `table1`? I'd expect the figures to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT show_users.id, COUNT(DISTINCT `table1`.id) as sum_fields , SUM(`table2`.count) as count_all
```